# Test failed with nested table: couldn't find SharedList with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I am using Rails 5.001 and I want to test a controller-function from shared_list. Shared_list is nested under shopping_list.

**shared_lists_controller_test.rb**

```
class SharedListsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  setup do
    new_shopping_list = shopping_lists(:shopping_list_drogerie)
    @heikoSharedList = shared_lists(:shared_list_heiko)
    @heiko = users(:user_heiko)
  end

test "should get edit" do
    login_as(@heiko)
    @heiko.confirmed_at = Time.now

    get edit_shared_list_url(@heikoSharedList.shopping_list.id, @heikoSharedList)

    assert_response :success
  end
```

However when I run the test, I get this error message:

```
Error:
SharedListsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find SharedList with 'id'=102138810
    test/controllers/shared_lists_controller_test.rb:49:in `block in <class:SharedListsControllerTest>'
```

Does somebody know what went wrong and how to fix this?
My fixtures look like this:

**shared_lists**

```
shared_list_heiko:
 user: user_heiko
 shopping_list: shopping_list_drogerie
 created_at: <%= Time.now %>
 updated_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

**shopping_lists**

```
shopping_list_drogerie:
 user: user_heiko
 name: Drogerie
 created_at: <%= Time.now %>
 updated_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

**model/list_item.rb**

```
class ListItem < ApplicationRecord
  # db associations
  belongs_to :shopping_list
  has_many :shopping_items

  # validations
  validates :shopping_list, :presence => true
  validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false
end
```

**model/shopping_list.rb**

```
class ShoppingList < ApplicationRecord
  # db associations
  belongs_to :user
  # if a shopping list is deleted, also delete information about all items on the list
  has_many :list_items, :dependent => :destroy
  # if a shopping list is deleted, also delete information about who it was shared with
  has_many :shared_lists , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :shared_with_users,through: :shared_lists, :source => :user

  has_many :invitation
  has_one :appointment

  # validations
  validates :user, :presence => true
  validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
end
```

**controllers/shopping_lists_controller.rb**

```
class ShoppingListsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /shopping_lists/1
  # GET /shopping_lists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # POST /shopping_lists
  # POST /shopping_lists.json
  def create

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to shopping_list_list_items_path(@shopping_list), alert: 'Shopping list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shopping_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shopping_lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /shopping_lists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_list.update(shopping_list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @shopping_list, notice: 'Shopping list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shopping_list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shopping_lists/1
  # DELETE /shopping_lists/1.json
  def destroy
      @shopping_list.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to shopping_lists_url, notice: 'Shopping list was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
   end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_shopping_list
      @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   private def shopping_list_params
      params.require(:shopping_list).permit(:name)
   end
end
```

Comment: Is there any more to the error msg ? (does the code actually hit the controller and model or does the test itself fail)

Comment: no there is nothing more to the error msg. I think the problem is something with the fact, that Shared_list is nested under shopping_list.

Comment: u mean a shared list belongs to shopping list? can u show the appropriate models in your code?

Comment: yes, I updated my thread, you can see now my models

Comment: Include the actual controller under test.

Comment: I added the controllers/shopping_lists_controller.rb